# How can I modify the display of this mySQL query in JSON with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I'm stuck with a chart, because I can't put the values like the chart requires. For example:

```
  ['Year', 'Sales'],
  ['2004',  1000],
  ['2005',  1170],
  ['2006',  660],
  ['2007',  1030]
```

And the query result in JSON is like this:

```
{"Date":"Nov 23, 2016","Total":"2","8AM-9AM":"0","9AM-10AM":"0","10AM-11AM":"0","11AM-12PM":"0","12PM-1PM":"0","1PM-2PM":"0","2PM-3PM":"0","3PM-4PM":"0","4PM-5PM":"0","5PM-6PM":"0","6PM-7PM":"0","7PM-8PM":"0","8PM-9PM":"0","9PM-10PM":"0","10PM-11PM":"0","11PM-12AM":"0","12AM-1AM":"1","1AM-2AM":"1","2AM-3AM":"0","3AM-4AM":"0","4AM-5AM":"0","5AM-6AM":"0","6AM-7AM":"0","7AM-8AM":"0"}
```

So I was thinking, Is the SQL query the problem? or Can I modify this query to adapt it in PHP?

This is the rest of the code involved:

```
$SQLDatos = "select DATE_FORMAT(hora, '%b %d, %Y') Date, 
  count(hora) as Total,

  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(hora) = 08 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '8AM-9AM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(hora) = 09 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '9AM-10AM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(hora) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '10AM-11AM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(hora) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '11AM-12PM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(hora) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '12PM-1PM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(hora) = 13 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '1PM-2PM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(hora) = 14 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '2PM-3PM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(hora) = 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '3PM-4PM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(hora) = 16 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '4PM-5PM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(hora) = 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '5PM-6PM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(hora) = 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '6PM-7PM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(hora) = 19 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '7PM-8PM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(hora) = 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '8PM-9PM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(hora) = 21 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '9PM-10PM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(hora) = 22 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '10PM-11PM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(hora) = 23 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '11PM-12AM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(hora) = 00 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '12AM-1AM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(hora) = 01 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '1AM-2AM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(hora) = 02 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '2AM-3AM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(hora) = 03 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '3AM-4AM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(hora) = 04 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '4AM-5AM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(hora) = 05 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '5AM-6AM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(hora) = 06 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '6AM-7AM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(hora) = 07 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '7AM-8AM'
from user_log
WHERE
  Date(`user_log`.`hora`) = Date_Add(CurDate(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) AND user_log.servicio = (select CodServicio from servicios where CodUsuario = 1024)
group by DATE_FORMAT(hora, '%b %d, %Y');";

//ejecutamos la consulta
$result = mysql_query($SQLDatos);
//obtenemos número filas
$numFilas = mysql_num_rows($result);

//cargamos array con los nombres de las métricas a visualizar
$datos = array();

//recorremos filas
 while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $rows = $r;
   }
    echo json_encode($rows);
```

And the Google Chart code:

```
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "aux_11.php",
          dataType: "json",
          async: true
          }).responseText;

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
       data.addColumn('number', 'Hora');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Cantidad');
     var options = {
title: '',
curveType: 'function',
legend: { position: 'right' }
};

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

chart.draw(data, options);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also convert the json object to the array and then use it to create google chart

```
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "aux_11.php",
      dataType: "json",
      async: true
    }).responseText;

    // split the json object into the array 
    var dataArray = [];
    var i = 0;
    $.each(jsonData, function(index, value){
        if((index!='Date') && (index!='Total')){
            value = parseInt(value);
            var row = [index, value];
            dataArray[i] = row;
            i++;
          }
    });

    // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Hora'); // this should be string 
    data.addColumn('number', 'Cantidad');
    data.addRows(dataArray);

    var options = {
        title: '',
        curveType: 'function',
        legend: { position: 'right' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
```

Comment: I think this might work, but gives me this error `jquery-1.10.2.js:631 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: Well.. I change the JQuery version and works, but doesnt show any data http://puu.sh/ssG4H/934ec39d50.png

Comment: Yes, same code, but my version of Jquery was 1.3, I changed it for 2.2.4, but doesnt give any data :c

Comment: well.. it worked fine on my side..i'm checking it again. Did you get any other error in your console?

Comment: This is the Chart http://puu.sh/ssGp4/904501b154.png  no errors, and this is the code http://puu.sh/ssGrl/fee19bc8dc.png. I dont know what im doing wrong  =/

Comment: just make a check if all the json object values are correct in the array use [console.log(dataArray)] after each loop

Comment: Now it work, I change the mysql query and all the code to the php file where the chart is, and put it this way   `$.each(<? echo json_encode($rows); ?>, function(index, value){` and now http://puu.sh/ssGT2/88af32ba78.png, Thank You Sir, you are a true Hero (Pastebin http://pastebin.com/2ap8dBDb)

Comment: happy to help =) #Victor

Answer (score 0):

You can sole this by use data.addRow

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData)

Change to
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable()
```

Than, use this to populate data to ur chart

```
data.addRow(["8AM-9AM", parseInt(jsonData.8AM-9AM)]);
data.addRow(["9AM-10AM", parseInt(jsonData.9AM-10AM)]);
...
```

Comment: thanks, this gives me and error parseInt(jsonData.9AM-10AM)]);

Comment: after the point doesnt recognize that as a javascript sentence http://puu.sh/ssDnJ/de42d9823d.png

Comment: owh ok, can you change 8AM-9AM in your sql statement to sumthing like am8am9, am9am10 than data.addRow(["8AM-9AM", parseInt(jsonData.am8am9)]);

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'am8am9' of undefined(…) :(

Comment: data.addRow(["8AM-9AM", parseInt(jsonData[2])]);
   data.addRow(["12AM-1AM", parseInt(jsonData[19])]); with this its works, but doesnt show anythingh the chart is empty but works

Comment: Also I change this 
 `var jsonData;
    $.ajax({
          url: "aux_11.php",
          dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
            jsonData = response;
 
  
  
      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
     var data = new google.visualization.DataTable()
  data.addColumn('string', 'Hora');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Cantidad');

 for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) { 

   data.addRow(["12AM-"+i+"AM", parseInt(jsonData[i])]);
  }`